# can I add custom attributes to components in preferences.xml without making custom views?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-xml, android-preferences

I am trying to store a state or data with some sort of custom attribute to existing components in the preferences.xml that I can later reference and read in code. I want to avoid creating custom views for all of these componenets if possible since that would mean I have to create a new custom view each time someone wants to add an attribute to a new component.

For example, I want to add `mycustomatt:forced="true"` to certain components as shown below.
Is this possible without creating custom views or is there an alternative solution that could be better?

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="300"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:key="coffeekey"
    mycustomatt:forced="true"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:title="@string/coffee" />
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="highprio"
    mycustomatt:forced="true"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:summary="@string/highpriocoffeedesc"
    android:title="@string/highpriocoffee" />
<RingtonePreference
    android:defaultValue="default"
    android:key="notiftone"
    mycustomatt:forced="true"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:ringtoneType="notification"
    android:summary="@string/notitonesum"
    android:title="@string/notitone" />
```

Comment: Maybe you can use android:tag here.

Comment: That is actaully what I am doing right now as a temporary solution, but it might be the best available option. I was not sure if that would be bad practice for some reason or if its considered ok. @SiddarthJain

Comment: If you don't want to create custom views and also wanted it to be in xml than android:tag is the only available option and also the best one.

Comment: Thank you, I answered my question to reflect your comment and will use this solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @SiddarthJain said in the comments - it seems the best and only way of doing this without creating custom views would be to use `android:tag` in my components, example below

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="highprio"
    android:tag="forced"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:summary="@string/highpriocoffeedesc"
    android:title="@string/highpriocoffee" />
```